# How to send cookies with guzzle 6?

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, guzzle6

Hi i'm trying to load this website that need a cookie "BHMCidade=1", I have read the documentation and it's not working with this code, why?

```
    $cookieJar = CookieJar::fromArray([
        'BHMCidade' => 1,
    ], 'http://www.bahamas.com.br');
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', "http://www.bahamas.com.br/ListaLojas.aspx?Area=Lojas", [
        'cookies' => $cookieJar,
    ]);

    $crawler = $this->client->getResponse()->getContent();
    print_r($crawler);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the domain just be `example.com` in the CookieJar-call instead of the complete URI to the php file?

Comment: i tought so too, but i was testing, doesn't work anyways

Comment: You're also making the request _before_ you call the `updateGuzzClient()`, so when the request is made, there are no cookies for it to send. You also need to show us what that method contains. Currently, your code doesn't show us in any way how you're actually trying to add the cookie jar. Try doing it as the manual does and see if that works: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#cookies

Comment: @MagnusEriksson well updateguzzleclient just adds an array to client since i have goutte too, anyways i tried like in documentation and still not working, where u place the cookie doing the request if cookies => $jar?

Comment: Instead of `$jar`, use your `$cookieJar`-variable. It should be the same thing.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this is my actual code and still not working, any ideas?    $cookieJar = CookieJar::fromArray([
            'BHMCidade' => 1,
        ], 'http://www.bahamas.com.br');
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', "http://www.bahamas.com.br/ListaLojas.aspx?Area=Lojas", [
            'cookies' => $cookieJar,
        ]);

        $crawler = $this->client->getResponse()->getContent();
        print_r($crawler);

(edit delete the full url but it has http etc)